# Research question about single-group interventions and data analysis

Tags: dataset

We are working with a community organization that had collected data on their own and want us to do data analysis. The data they sent us showed they gave everyone their (anti-smoking) intervention and did follow-ups at a few time points. There is little demographic information but there is information on self-efficacy and a few other things like length of time smoking, frequency, etc.

I was wondering what the best analyses for this limited data would be. GEE and intention-to-treat don't seem appropriate as there's only one group, but doing a simple repeated measures analyses leads to inflated quit rates. We would definitely appreciate any advice on appropriate analyses given the circumstances. We are hoping to continue working with the organization to improve their methods, but we wanted to at least try to do something with what they had collected, keeping in mind the limitations.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I've been reading textbooks and other academic sources online regarding longitudinal analyses, but pretty much every example I'm coming across is comparing some experiment or intervention with a control group. The most promising sections of these chapters are regression, but I don't know how to account for quit rate inflation.

Comment: The problem, as you recognize, is that without a control group there is no way to know whether the intervention itself mattered. You don't say why you think that the repeated-measures analysis gave "inflated quit rates"; the quit rates might be correct but unrelated to the intervention. For example, a coincident large increase in cigarette taxes could lead to a high quit rate.

Comment: Would it be an option to create a control group post hoc? A control group only requires two measurements, this is not a lot of work. It would make the analysis more powerful.

Comment: You both make good points. This data crosses several years and I don't know that a post-hoc control group would be a good idea given that cultural norms surrounding smoking can and have probably changed (or rather, moved further in the same direction they have been moving) and so the two groups wouldn't necessarily be comparable. 

I guess I really am stuck with just running repeated measures and acknowledging that this doesn't tell us much, due to design issues. I guess in the back of my head I was just hoping for something else that could help. Thank you both!

Comment: As for inflated quit rates, I just mean that those that drop off the face of the planet (in other words, we can't contact them) are probably less likely to have stopped smoking than those who stuck with the intervention, who we could contact.